# how do i use my android tablet as a wired xbox 360 controller

Tags: usb

I want to know how to use my tablet as a wired Xbox 360 controller for games, without using a computer or Wi-Fi.

Comment: You mean using Smartglass app (basic controls)? If not, I would image you can't without remote desktop to a PC.

Comment: When you say "without using a computer", do you mean you want to use it with a real XBox 360? Why? It's going to be so much less useful than a real XBox 360 controller. What's the tablet and what Android version does it have?